# How do I replace substrings that start with 'X' and end with '.tif'?

Tags: powershell

I have a string that includes both data and the names of image files, delineated by tabs

The names of the image files are 41 characters long and end with the file extension .tif (example: X1126225548817153725411111_PPPPP_00333.tif)

I would like to remove the substrings that match the following criteria, but I'm not sure which string tricks to use

Comment: So what result would you expect? What have you tried so far?

Comment: If this is a one-time task, you can use a utility like Advanced Renamer and so on.

Comment: So far I've tried $data[1].Replace( "X*tif","") and many other variations but it doesn't remove the file.

$data[1].Replace( "tif","")  and $data[1].Replace( "X","") get rid of the characters correctly, but I can't figure out how to replace the whole substring

Comment: Can you be more accurate please. You want to get file names, then to remove file extension and starting letter X. Is that correct? If yes, what you need to do whit the output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to rename these files:

```
get-childitem "YourDirectory\*.tif" | 
foreach { $newName = ($_.BaseName).TrimStart("X")
          Rename-Item $_.FullName $newName }
```

Basename removes the file extension, and TrimStart("X") removes the leading "X".

Comment: I need to keep the files the way they are. 


I want to turn my data from this:                                                                                      

X1126220122222253703437_01_13335_00001.tif 3 2 1  3 3 3 3 X1126220122222253703437_02_13333_00001.tif 2 2 2 2 2
                                                                                                                           
into this:                                                                 


3 2 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using the wrong wildcard for regular expressions

Here's the code:

```
PS C:\Users\mharper> $data[1] -Replace "X......................................tif\`t" , ""\`
        -Replace "\`t\`t" , "`t"
```